# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android

Подгружаю данные с сервера порциями. Новые порции загружаются при прокрутке экрана. Подгружаю с помощью AsyncTask.   
В списке есть простые элементы и элементы-группы. Если кликнуть по группе, то открывается другая активити, в которой подгружаются только элементы группы.    
Проблема в следующем: захожу в группу, выхожу, захожу в другую группу и вылетает ошибка:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Все никак не пойму, как ее исправить.. Вот мой AsyncTask

```
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    protected ProgressBar proBar;
    protected TextView proText;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        proBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        proBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        proText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_text);
        proText.setText("loading...");
        proText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // TODO ссылка
        ReadStringJson rsj = new ReadStringJson(SERVER_URL_1 + SERVER_PATH_2 + SERVER_PATH_3 + GROUP 
                + "&from=" + (from + 1) + "&number=" + number + SERVER_PATH_4 + FILTER);

        try {
            parsingData(rsj.readFromServer());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             Log.e("IOException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
             Log.e("JSONException: ", ex.toString());
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter.addEnginesNames(names);
        adapter.addEnginesDescriptions(descriptions);
        adapter.addEnginesLogoUrl(logoUrl);
        adapter.addIsGroup(isGroup);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: parsingData не модифицирует адаптер? Вам нужно найти все места возможной модификации адаптера и проверить, что вызываете notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, parsingData ничего с адаптером не делает, там просто идет парсинг json. Единственное место, где обновляется адаптер - это onPostExecute

Comment: @KoVadim, есть идеи, в чем косяк?

Comment: Есть. Проблема  случайно не воспроизводиться, если во время работы asynctask повернуть экран?

Comment: Как раз он и должен приводить к проблеме (потому что AsyncTask будет висеть в фоне и вызовет обновление, когда активити пересоздалось).

Comment: нет, при повороте ничего такого не вылезает..     
разве что, подгрузка идет немного не в том порядке, но экспепшн не вылетает

Comment: пропустил в вопросе "Проблема в следующем: захожу в группу, выхожу, захожу в другую группу и вылетает ошибка:"

Вот это и проблема. Как и при повороте, так и при входе-выходе, активити пересоздается. Остается старый AsyncTask. Он пытается обновить ListView, которого уже нет.

Comment: хорошо, но поворот экрана все-равно никак приложение не ломает...    
Что посоветуешь для решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Русским языком же написано, что обновление адаптера надо проводить в UI потоке!

Что означает, что обновление адаптера надо вывести из-под `AsyncTask`

Comment: onPostExecute выполняется в UI потоке.

Comment: @Barmaley, как же тогда нужно обновлять адаптер то, если не в onPostExecute?